# How to approach setting up domain2 (server2) pointing to domain1 (server1) and creating 2 subdomains on domain2 for 2 apps both using SSL?

Tags: linux, apache, web-hosting, ionos

How to approach setting up **domain2** (**server2**) pointing to **domain1** (**server1**) and creating 2 subdomains on **domain2** for 2 apps?

**server2** has **Apache** loaded on it.
**server1** is a **3rd-party web host**.

I have a wildcard SSL on my server2 for the 2 apps.
**app1** is on port **443**
**app2** is on port **444**

I've gotten both of these subdomain apps to run locally.

It has blown up though for me once I tried to get them to have SSL by setting up my **3rd-party web host** dns records.

If someone can help solve this puzzle for me, I'd appreciate.

I've tried setting it up the dns on the **3rd-party hosting** with a subdomain forwarding to my server2, but the IP was changing and the SSL was complaining.